# 'translate is not a function'-error in react admin with react testing library and jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-admin

I'm trying to write a test with React Testing Library and Jest. However, I'm getting a `TypeError: translate is not a function` error. As suggested by [React Admin Documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html#usetranslate-hook), I'm using the `useTranslate` hook. In the test, I'm using the `jest.mock` function to mock the 'react-admin' package and all the test does at the moment, is check if the component renders. All dependencies have been updated.

Right now, the test chokes on the translate const with the useTranslate hook. I tried to add `translate` to the `jest.mock` the same way as `useTranslate`, but no dice. I also did a `console.log(typeof translate)` to prove it actually is a function, which returned `function`. Any suggestions on what I could/should do to pass the test?

Here is my code:

```js
// in src/admin/Organization/OrganizationShow.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
import {
  useTranslate,
  Show,
  Tab,
  TabbedShowLayout,
  TextField,
  DateField,
} from 'react-admin';
import { HeaderTitle } from '../../components';

export const OrganizationShow = (props: any) => {
  const translate = useTranslate();

  return (
    <Show {...props} title={<HeaderTitle i18n="show.title" />}>
      <TabbedShowLayout>
        <Tab label={translate('show.details')}>
          <TextField source="name" label={translate('data.name')} />
          <DateField source="started" label={translate('data.started')} />
          <DateField
            source="ended"
            label={translate('data.ended')}
            emptyText="-"
          />
        </Tab>
        <Tab label={translate('show.apps')} path="apps">
          <p>{translate('page.not_yet')}</p>
        </Tab>
        <Tab label={translate('show.authentication')} path="auth">
          <p>{translate('page.not_yet')}</p>
        </Tab>
      </TabbedShowLayout>
    </Show>
  );
};
```

```js
// in src/__tests__/Organization.test.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { OrganizationShow } from '../admin/Organization/OrganizationShow';

// Mock React Admin so we don't have to resolve it
// Do not take this into account for the example
// The tests are valid if react-admin package is installed
jest.mock('react-admin', () => ({
  useTranslate: (key: string) => key,
  Show: () => <div />,
  Tab: () => <div />,
  TabbedShowLayout: () => <div />,
  TextField: () => <div />,
  DateField: () => <div />,
}));

// Suppress PropTypes warning by default
const defaultProps = {
  location: {},
  match: {},
};

describe('OrganizationShow', () => {
  it('App renders successfully', () => {
    render(<OrganizationShow {...defaultProps} />);
  });
});
```

```bash
FAIL src/__tests__/Organization.test.tsx
  OrganizationShow
    ✕ App renders successfully (91 ms)

  ● OrganizationShow › App renders successfully

    TypeError: translate is not a function

      17 |     <Show {...props} title={<HeaderTitle i18n="show.title" />}>
      18 |       <TabbedShowLayout>
    > 19 |         <Tab label={translate('show.details')}>
         |                     ^
      20 |           <TextField source="name" label={translate('data.name')} />
      21 |           <DateField source="started" label={translate('data.started')} />
      22 |           <DateField
```

```json
// in package.json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.0.16",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.19.0",
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^12.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`useTranstale` hook returns function, so Your mocked version should be like:

```
useTranslate: () => (key: string) => key,
```